# Making a call on a registered sip profile with freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I have a sip profile set up with freeswitch as

```
<include>
 <gateway name="[sipname]">
  <param name="register" value="false"/>
  <param name="username" value="not-used"/>
  <param name="password" value="not-used"/>
  <param name="realm" value="[ip address]"/>
  <param name="proxy" value="[ip address]"/>
 </gateway>
</include>
```

Am I right in thinking I should be able to make a call with:

```
originate sofia/external/[phonenumber]@[ip address] '&javascript(/root/voice.js 20)'
```

Because I keep getting RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE and before I investigate all the other problems it could be I wanted to check that I'm doing it right so far.

Comment: thanks for originate example, after making call like that my linphone users started to register, before that i couldn't

Answer (score 1):

**Dial out of a gateway**

Basic form:

> `*sofia/gateway/<gateway>/<number_to_dial>*`

Example 1:

> `*sofia/gateway/asterlink/18005551212*`

http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_sofia#Dial_out_of_a_gateway

> `originate sofia/gateway/[sipname]/[phonenumber] &javascript('/root/voice.js 20')`

Answer (score 0):

```
originate {ignore_early_media=true,bridge_early_media=false,originate_timeout=24,call_timeout=24,execute_on_answer='sched_hangup 10 alloted_timeout',origination_uuid=f7f927c5-n6wv-a55j-m5cr-37c9-f7f934d95e,origination_caller_id_number=+12121112222}sofia/gateway/asterisk/+14171111111 handle_calls
```

In this case asterisk is my profile under `/sip_profiles/external/asterisk.xml`

```
> sofia status gateway asterisk 
=================================================================================================
Name        asterisk
Profile     external
Scheme      Digest
Realm       192.241.203.11:5090
Username    FreeSWITCH
Password    no
From        <sip:FreeSWITCH@192.241.203.21:5090>
Contact     <sip:gw+asterisk@2.67.78.1:5090;transport=udp;gw=asterisk>
Exten       FreeSWITCH
To          sip:FreeSWITCH@192.241.203.11:5090
Proxy       sip:192.241.203.11:5090
Context     public
Expires     3600
Freq        3600
Ping        0
PingFreq    0
PingTime    0.00
PingState   0/0/0
State       NOREG
Status      UP
Uptime      290s
CallsIN     0
CallsOUT    2
FailedCallsIN   0
FailedCallsOUT  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Talking about FreeSWITCH not Asterisk. The dial command is incorrect - through gateway it should be:

fs_cli> originate sofia/external/[phonenumber]@[gateway name] '&yourscript'

Answer (score -1):

First run fs_cli and command "sofia status" to check gateway is UP

Comment: This is not about checking sofia status, His dial format is wrong.